# Injection from $\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ to derangements of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be the set of the permutations without fixed points of $\mathbb{N}$.

Is there an elegant way to exhibit an injection from the power set $\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)$ to $S$ ?

(Clearly such an injection exists because $\left|\mathcal P \left({\mathbb{N}}\right)\right|=\left|S \right|=2^{\aleph_0}$)

Answer (score 2):

(There is a huge amount of leeway, that can be used for instance to arrange that the permutation codes some additional information.) Here is an example. Given $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ define $\pi\in S$ by: If $n\in A$, $\pi(4n+i)=4n+i+1$ for $i<3$ and $\pi(4n+3)=4n$. If $n\notin A$, $\pi(4n)=4n+2,\pi(4n+2)=4n$, $\pi(4n+1)=4n+3$ and $\pi(4n+3)=4n+1$.

Comment: $S$ is the set of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ WITHOUT fixed points.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It is now fixed.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo : Nice answer  !